# Python3 multiprocessing module not found with yocto/poky install

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh, python-multiprocessing, yocto

I am currently trying to run a 8(very small) bokeh app on a Zynq running poky from a yocto build.
When using the command `bokeh serve myplot.py` from a virtualenv with python 3.5.2, it returns : `ERROR:No module named 'multiprocessing'`.

However, in a python 2.7.14 virtualenv it works flawlessly.
From what I understand, the multiprocessing module should be already included to python. I couldn't find any python-multiprocessing for the build either.

I'm adding the python packages in `build/conf/local.conf`

```
#Adding extra packages
#Python 3
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL = "python3 python3-core python3-pip python3-numpy python3-flask"
#Python 2.7
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += "python python-core python-pip python-numpy python-flask"
```

How can I install the multiprocessing module for python3, either by including it in the build (favorite option) or after the build, when I'm running poky on the Zynq (least favorite option but I would be curious to know how).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the python recipe in rocko](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-devtools/python/python-3.5-manifest.inc?h=rocko) there is a package called `python3-multiprocessing`, so you should be able to just add `python3-multiprocessing` to `CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL`.